# 1. Given a group homomorphism $\psi: A_{8}\rightarrow S_{9}$ for which exists $\sigma\in A_{8}$ with $\psi(\sigma)=(12)$

Tags: group-theory

What i've tried:

The group homomorphism $\psi:A_{8}\rightarrow S_{9}$ for which $\sigma\in A_{8}$  with $\psi(\sigma)=(12)$  and $A_{8}$ is simple group according to the alternating group the alternating group theorem. Now we are to show that $\psi$ is injective or $\psi(\sigma)=e$
for all $\sigma\in A_{8}$.  Since $A_{8}$ contain no proper nontrivial normal subgroup.

can anyone help me out please.

Appreciate your help

Comment: The identical question was asked a few days ago - where does it come from? It seems nonsensical, because there are no homomorphisms $\psi:A_8 \to S_9$ with $\psi(\sigma) = (1,2)$.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is, in fact! Your title, for example, is not even a complete sentence.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez  Neither do I, but it has been asked at least three times! If $\psi(\sigma) = (12)$, then how could it possibly be true that $\psi(\sigma)=e$ for all $\sigma \in A_8$?

Answer (score 2):

You probably know that every homomorphism from a simple group is either the trivial homomorphism, or it is injective. So, *if* $\psi:A_8\to S_9$ as you describe exists, is it the trivial homomorphism? What then can you conclude?

Comment: @ ittay correct me if am wrong, but i know that trivial homomorphism mapping meant mapping everything to the identy.

Comment: That is correct @Lynnie.  When mathematicians say a homomorphism $\phi: G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ is trivial, they mean $\phi(x) = \operatorname{id_{G_2}}$ for all $x \in G_1$.

Comment: @ Kaj Hansen but i donot know how to show that.

Comment: @Lynnie ask yourself: is the given psi trivial?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

For any homomorphism $\phi:G_1 \rightarrow G_2$, prove that $\ker(\phi)$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1$.  Thus, we know that any homomorphism $\phi: A_8 \rightarrow S_9$ is either injective or trivial.

This can be extended to show that any homomorphism from a simple group is either trivial or an isomorphism to its image.

Comment: an isomorphism to its image, not all of $G_2$ (this is practically the first isomorphism theorem applied to this case)